# Package environments are not working as expected in a pipeline

Tags: r, environment-variables, pipe

In a package I'm working on, I'm using environments to save and retrieve the labels of a dataframe.

In a `magrittr` pipeline, I want to save them in an environment variable which I would retrieve later.

However, I'm facing a problem: it seems as if the environment variables were not modified until the end of the pipeline.

Here is an example, with most of useful functions:

```
devtools::install_github("DanChaltiel/crosstable", build_vignettes=TRUE)
library(crosstable) #for functions set_label() and get_label() but you can test 
                    #with other label-management packages (Hmisc, expss...)

labels_env = rlang::new_environment()
save_labels = function(.tbl){
    labels_env$last_save = tibble(
        name=names(.tbl),
        label=get_label(.tbl)[.data$name]
    )
    invisible(.tbl)
}
get_last_save = function(){
    labels_env$last_save
}
import_labels = function(.tbl){
    data_label = get_last_save()
    for(i in 1:nrow(data_label)){
        name = as.character(data_label[i, name_from])
        label = as.character(data_label[i, label_from])
        .tbl[name] = set_label(.tbl[name], label)
    }
    .tbl
}
```

This works exactly as intended, as label for `disp` would be `NULL` otherwise:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(crosstable)
save_labels(mtcars2)
mtcars2 %>%
  transmute(disp=as.numeric(disp)+1) %>%  #removes the label attribute of disp
  import_labels() %>% #
  crosstable(disp)
#>    .id                 label   variable               value
#> 1 disp Displacement (cu.in.)  Min / Max        72.1 / 473.0
#> 2 disp Displacement (cu.in.)  Med [IQR] 197.3 [121.8;327.0]
#> 3 disp Displacement (cu.in.) Mean (std)       231.7 (123.9)
#> 4 disp Displacement (cu.in.)     N (NA)              32 (0)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, `save_labels(mtcars2)` returns `mtcars2` invisibly so I'd like to be able to pipe the whole sequence. Unfortunately, this throws an error:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(crosstable)
mtcars2 %>%
  save_labels() %>% 
  transmute(disp=as.numeric(disp)+1) %>%
  import_labels() %>% #
  crosstable(disp)
#> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact): attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Indeed, when using pipes, the environment variable is not set yet when we get to `import_labels()`. If I re-run this code, it won't throw any error but that would be misleading as it would refer to the previous value of `labels_env$last_save`.

My understanding of pipes is not good enough to get this working. Moreover, it seems to be specific to the package environment, as I could not reproduce this behavior in a plain R script.

Is there a way I can use pipes with such an environment variable inside a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually caused by a breaking change when the package `magrittr` (which provides pipes) went from v1.5 to v2.0.

This was explained on [the blog](http://%20https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/11/magrittr-2-0-is-here/#sequential-evaluation) and [on NEWS.md](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/blob/master/NEWS.md#failures-caused-by-laziness).

A more specific reproducible example can be found on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/242).

In the new `magrittr` version, the evaluation sequenced has changed, so for side effects to happen in the correct order, you have to force the evaluation:

```
import_labels = function(.tbl){
    force(.tbl) #force evaluation
    data_label = get_last_save()
    for(i in 1:nrow(data_label)){
        name = as.character(data_label[i, name_from])
        label = as.character(data_label[i, label_from])
        .tbl[name] = set_label(.tbl[name], label)
    }
    .tbl
}
```